# Ruby on rails gem social-share-button doesn't work in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to use the [social-share-button gem](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button).

I first tried with the localhost and it worked very well. I can share what I want with Twitter, Whatsapp, E-mail...

Everything seemed to work well. But when I try the share btn on my heroku app, it doesn't work. The link just do nothing except adding a "#" in my Url. In the Heroku logs I can not see any errors.

Since it is working in development, I do not find any mistake in my local server.

I don't think that the problem is from the button itself. I made several tries by modifying the url, the social-medias... for the same results, it works in my localhost but not on my Heroku app. Maybe it is because I use rails 5.2.3 and I missed something in the configuration.

Anyway, I hope that someone can help me ! Thanks